Finding an average $\%$ for multiple weeks to arrive at total
I have an average of $3.28\%$ through $29$ weeks.  I need to know what I would need to average each week of weeks $30-52$ to arrive at a yearly average of $3\%$? What is the excel formula?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please edit your post as it seems you have left out some important information

You have not provided enough information to answer your question.
Suppose a basketball player shoots 47% in one game. You can't know how well he has to do in the next game to increase his success rate to 60% without knowing how many shots he tried in the first game.
If he takes and makes just one shot in the second game he will have 100% success there. How would you calculate his overall success rate with just that new information?
